# String data to tree

Tags: php, mysql

I am building a family tree program using PHP and MySQL and almost completed it. My main program works on 3 tables: individual, child and spouse. As you can guess the last 2 tables are just relation tables and with this I can render an entire family tree. The table `"individual"` holds all family members with details such as `Gender, date of birth, date of death, email, first name, last name` etc while "`child"` table has just 2 columns - `parentID and childID`, `"spouse"` table has `"individaulID"` and `"spouseID"`.

Now there is a requirement to show only relation tree for selected nodes. The data that I will receive is like this:

```
"P(13)=14,P(14)=15,P(15)=16,C(16)=17,S(17)=18,C(17)=19"
```

Here "P(13)=14" means 14 is parent of 13, "C(16)=17" means 17 is child of 16 and "S(17)=18" means 18 is spouse of 17.

I dont want to create temp tables because with multiple users the temp tables can cause issues. Any ideas on how to parse this data and create UL LI structure?

Thanks,
Sudhir

Comment: Is this layout imposed on you or can you change it? Having a simple relationship table with type(C/S), previous, next would simplify the query. Otherwise, you have to follow the relationships, switching between tables, before finally reading in the details.

Comment: Yes Mike, the layout is imposed and I cant change it. When I render full tree I just run queries on these 3 tables and it works fine. The issue is now with string data coming in when 2 nodes are selected.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. What I did is as follows: 
 From the string I can find the topmost node. Also I can find required user IDs in the string and store the list in $valid_ids. So I ran my original script using top node as the ID and modified the SQLs to include

```
"individual_id in ($valid_ids)"
```

in the where clause